# SQLEXPRESS user login error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I'm trying to fire a web application from my local pc and it throws the error "Login failed for user DOMAIN\USER" (please note that I didn't type my actual values for the DOMAIN and USER in the above error).

- I connect to SQLEXPRESS
- Database is added through MSSMS and a new user is added to the DB with the values from connection string.
- Changed authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode but still the same error.
- Changed connection string with Windows login details but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to login using SQL authentication or Windows authentication? It sounds like you are trying to login using SQL authentication (i.e. named SQL User and password), but your connection string is indicating to use windows authentication (something like SSPI=True)

So you need to verify what login method you want to use: Windows or SQL
Then you need to post your connection string